# How do I rewrite this URL in Apache using mod rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect

```
"/w/index.php?title=TITLE_HERE&oldid=100"
```

to

```
"/wiki/TITLE_HERE.php".
```

I tried several things, but the following RedirectMatch should work based on my research. I read quite a bit about rewriting in the different ways in Apache. The problem, of course, is that it does not work. I am not redirected at all when I visit

```
"/w/index.php?title=Example_Article&oldid=100".
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
RedirectMatch "^/w/index\.php?title=([^&]+)" "/wiki/$1.php"
```

I have many other, working redirect/rewrite rules. I don't understand why this one doesn't work.

I tried with and without surrounding quotes. I also tried to add ".*$" at the end, in case a complete match is required, but no luck.

The character class [^&] means one instance of any character that is NOT '&'. Then I want one or more of those with the "+" quantifier (greedy matching, of course). This should make it cut out the "&oldid=100" and make things smooth. But the redirect isn't even triggering.

I also tried "(.+)" to see if the negated regex character class wasn't supported, but was not redirected then either.

By the way, my site is NOT a wiki. It used to be. Now it is static HTML. And this is why the redirects would be beneficial. I know you can rewrite the URLs differently in for instance MediaWiki.

(This is my first Stack Overflow question, so bear with me.)

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do confirm once if you are hitting link like: `http://localhost:80/w/index.php?title=TITLE_HERE&oldid=100` in your browser?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. The link I'm trying is https://www.example.com/w/index.php?title=Article_Title&oldid=1459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of any other rewrite rules (below the internal redirect rewrite-rules (those without the flag `[R]`)):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/w\/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)title=(.+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ /wiki/%1.php [R=302,L,NE]
```

If you are confused, the difference between `$1` and `%1` is: `%1` gets the previous captured string from `RewriteCond`, and `$1` is just like the usual RegEx back-reference, and only contains stuff from the current `RewriteRule`.

Comment: It seems like you haven't looked at my answer's rewrite-rules properly.

In your answer, you say that you used `(.+)(&|$)`, but I have mentioned `(.*)(?:&|$)`!, and you said that it didn't redirect in the browser, but I have already mentioned `[R=302]`

Comment: @SvendsenTech Did you see my RewriteRule properly? I have already mentioned [R=302] when I was answering. Look at it again please

Comment: The difference between .* and .+ is that the former means zero or more and the latter one or more. They are equivalent as long as there is at least one letter in the string. I cannot make my regular regex knowledge work properly here in mod_rewrite. But I have a working solution now.

Comment: @SvendsenTech you have misunderstood how apache shows the query string.

Comment: @SvendsenTech, look at the $_SERVER variable in php, and you will understand how the query string is shown in QUERY_STRING

Comment: "*Yes, I left it out because I read here on SO that during testing it's not such a good idea, because the browser caches*" Browser only caches 301.

Comment: Sorry about the mess here, really... It's working with this: "RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)title=([^&]+)". I tried yet another approach. Have not checked the $_SERVER variable yet (not sure how.. echo in a .php?). But there's a problem with URLs with spaces. They become "%2520" which I read is a "double-encoded space" somewhere else on SO. It caches 301 and not 302 according to you, so I took a leap of faith and am now using your exact solution, except for the slightly different query above (yours should work too, could caching be playing a role here in the confusion?).

Comment: @SvendsenTech any example for an URL with spaces?

Comment: @SvendsenTech oh that is what you mean, I get it now. The issue is that we are taking a backreference and that backreference is not being un-escaped

Comment: @SvendsenTech Did you try my updated one? I have edited it. Try it now

Comment: Adding the "NE" ("no escaping"?) flag to the [] part worked. The way there was a bit weird. Hope that's not a security issue?

Comment: @SvendsenTech, hmm... I cannot guarantee. But I do not know any other way of doing this.

Comment: That's all I can help here. I would suggest to delete all the comments here to avoid confusion in the future when people visit this.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/w/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)title=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /wiki/%1.php [R=302,L,NE]
```

Using "(.+)(&|$)" at the end did not work for me. Page not found, and no redirect.

NB! The URL in the browser bar did not update before I added "[R=302,L]". Now it updates. The solution here appends the query for index.php to the URL after a question mark, so it becomes:

```
/wiki/Article_Name.php?title=Article_Name&oldid=100
```

This at least works for showing the web page with my setup. There are now a few hundred less dead links on the internet, I think, if I got it right in the end.

Comment: Your RewriteCond is not secure. Someone can set `xyztitle=123` and it will redirect to wiki/123.php

Comment: I think caching is playing a role in causing confusion here. Currently investigating (with your help).

Comment: No caching is not an issue here. Apache itself is not decoding the query_string here I think